# I have an error with system.out.print and I don't know why?

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
public class Outline {

        int rowIndex=62;//hsample number
        int colIndex=2;//sample number, will be determined by RNG when I'm done

        String val=read1(rowIndex,colIndex);

        System.out.print(val);//This is where the error is, I don't know what's wrong with it.



    public static final String FILE_NAME = "Copy_of_Words.xls";

    public static String read1(int rowIndex, int colIndex){

        String value = new String();
        HSSFWorkbook wb = null;


        try {
            wb= new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(FILE_NAME));
        } catch (Exception e){//in here, say what needs to be done

        }

        HSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheet("SAT"); //here, user input will determine sheet
        HSSFRow row=sheet.getRow(rowIndex-1);
        HSSFCell cell=row.getCell(colIndex-1);

        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
        value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);

        return value;
    }       
}
```

What exactly is the problem with system.out.print(val)? I can't figure it out. I'm using apache and excel in the program, but I don't think that should cause problems.

Comment: What exactly is the error message?

Comment: What error are you getting? Is it compile time or run time? if runtime add the exception stacktrace

Comment: *Never* state in a question "I have an error" without saying what that error is. See http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: "Syntax error on token "val", VariableDeclaratorID expected after this token" and "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)" are the error messages, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

You can't use

```
 System.out.print(val);
```

Out side a method. You should put `System.out.print(val);` inside a method.

```
public void myMethod(){
   System.out.print(val);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You try to execute a statement in the class body. You can't do that.

Every statement must be inside a method (or a constructor or an initializer block).

Only declarations (method/field/constructor/...) can be directly in the class body.

Comment: +1 for mentioning initializer blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Your

```
System.out.print(val);
```

is out side the method scope.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.print(val);
```

This statement must be present in some function.

Answer (score 2):

Classes are defined this way:

```
class MyClass {
    // field, constructor, and 
    // method declarations
}
```

You can't execute statements there. They should be located inside a *method*. See [Declaring Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html).

Answer (score 1):

You cant invoke

```
System.out.print(val);
```

on class level. If you want to execute some code then you need to place it in

- methods (like `public static void main(String[] args){...}`),
- constructors,
- or initializing blocks

Answer (score 0):

Write ur statement

```
  System.out.print(val);
```

either in Function or main function.